# Left join in view with condition on the left table but still want all records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date dimension table from which I want to left join to another table in order to show records (worker_availability) that exist for dates for the next couple weeks, for instance.

Date Dimension simply has every date for the next hundred years.

```
SELECT 
dd.date_actual,
wa.worker_id,
string_agg(sh.name, ', ')
FROM public.worker_availability wa
LEFT JOIN public.d_date dd on wa.day = dd.date_actual --and wa.worker_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
LEFT JOIN public.shift sh on sh.shift_id = wa.shift_id
where 
wa.worker_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND
dd.date_actual >= NOW()

GROUP BY dd.date_actual, wa.worker_id
ORDER BY dd.date_actual asc
LIMIT 100
```

If I violate a principle of left join and use a where, then the results are incorrect.

If I add WHERE (worker_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' OR wa.* IS NULL) then the results are still incorrect.

I want to see every date regardless of if there is a worker_availability record for the date.

The issue is that if I filter the left worker_availability left join (which works), then I can no longer make this query into a view and use it from EntityFramework because I cannot use the worker_id column in a where clause.

Comment: Why are you left-joinin `d_date`? I would have assumed all dates in `wa` were already present in the date dimension; if that's the case an inner join should be used.

Comment: Move your condition from the `where` to the `on`.. I see you already tried that and commented it out. Didn't it work as expected?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, that works perfectly except I intend to create a view from this query and if I keep the condition in the "on", I would not be able to filter the view from the worker_id column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add that info to the question?

Comment: Done @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: If you want this to be a view, you cross join the date calendar with the list of workers to get every possible date for every possible worker. Then you left join to availability. Then you can filter your view, keeping in mind that query planner is smart enough to pre filter data if you use a `where` clause on it. Alternatively you could create a table valued function which takes a worker parameter. But I suggest the view first because it will allow you to see more than one worker in the dataset